# How to display downloaded image to ImageView with SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listview, imageview, simpleadapter

I'm trying to display images in respective ImageViews of a listView created using Simple Adapter. So far the images are downloading fine to a location on disk, and text data is displaying fine in the listView but I'm having trouble displaying the downloaded images to the correct positions of the listView items. My code looks like this so far...

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // More Code Here
        ...

        productList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

        this.getListView().setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
                // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to your
                // AdapterView
                customLoadMoreDataFromApi(page);
                // or customLoadMoreDataFromApi(totalItemsCount);
            }
        });

        addInitialLoader();
        addKeyListener();

        // Get listview
        lv = getListView();

    }

    // Append more data into the adapter
    public void customLoadMoreDataFromApi(int offset) {
        // This method probably sends out a network request and appends new data items to your adapter. 
        // Use the offset value and add it as a parameter to your API request to retrieve paginated data.
        // Deserialize API response and then construct new objects to append to the adapter
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            //"...loading more items" + offset + "...",
            //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        final Toast tost2 = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "...loading more items" + offset + "...",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        tost2.show();

        Handler handler2 = new Handler();
        handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               tost2.cancel(); 
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    public void addInitialLoader() {
        // get Internet status
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

        // check for Internet status
        if (isInternetPresent) {
            // Internet Connection is Present
            // make HTTP requests

            new JSONParse().execute();
            return;
        } else {
            // Internet connection is not present
            // Ask user to connect to Internet
            showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    "No Internet Connection",
                    "You don't have internet connection.", false);
        }
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            // Some code Here
            ...

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Clear previous list items
            productList.clear();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url,
                "GET", params);

            if (json != null) {

                try {
                    // Getting JSON Array

                    Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();
                    while (keys.hasNext()) {
                        String key = keys.next();
                        String pid = "";
                        String img = "";
                        String weight = "";
                        String name = "";
                        String desciption = "";
                        String price = "";
                        int maxLen = 15;
                        int maxLen2 = 20;

                        JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(key);
                        String err = c.getString(TAG_ERROR) == "false" ? "" : "true";

                        if (err == "true") {
                           pid = "0";
                           img = "0";
                           weight = "0";
                           name = "None";
                           desciption = "none";
                           price = "none";

                        } else {
                           pid = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                           img = c.getString(TAG_IMAG);
                           weight = c.getString(TAG_SIZE);
                           name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                           desciption = c.getString(TAG_DESCR);
                           price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);

                        }

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, Object> cartitem = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        cartitem.put(TAG_PID, pid);
                        cartitem.put(TAG_IMAG, R.drawable.logo);
                        cartitem.put(TAG_IMP, img);
                        cartitem.put(TAG_SIZE, "Size: " + qty);
                        cartitem.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        cartitem.put(TAG_DESCR, desciption);
                        cartitem.put(TAG_SIZE, weight);

                        if (err == "") {
                           cartitem.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
                        } else {
                            cartitem.put(TAG_PRICE,
                                    "Error: No cart to show or items are already delivered.");
                        }

                        // adding product details to product list
                        productList.add(cartitem);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    Log.e("ERROR Exception: ", e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // Internet connection is not present

                Log.e("ERROR Json: ", "No Internet Available");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            // protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(json);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

                /**
                * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                * */

                // Keys used in Hashmap
                String[] from = { TAG_SIZE, TAG_NAME, TAG_DESCR, TAG_PRICE, TAG_PID };

                // Ids of views in listview_layout
                int[] to = { R.id.size, R.id.name, R.id.descr, R.id.price, R.id.pid };

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                productList, R.layout.list_item, from, to);

                setListAdapter(adapter);

                //Log.i("Adapter Count:", ""+adapter.getCount());

                for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                    HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);

                    String imgUrl = (String) hm.get(TAG_IMP);
                    ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

                    // HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    // Only put images that are set
                    String needle = "img/nophoto.png";
                    if(!needle.equals(imgUrl)) {
                        hm.put("img_path", imgUrl);
                        hm.put("position", i);
                        Log.i("HM:", hm.toString());

                        imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
                    } 

                    // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in the listview

                }

            }
        }
    }

    /** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView */
    private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

            InputStream iStream=null;
            String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("img_path");
            //imgUrl = imgUrl.replace("\\/", "");
            imgUrl = imgrl + imgUrl;
            int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

            Log.i("IMGURL:", imgUrl);

            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(imgUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                // Getting Caching directory
                File cacheDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); //getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

                if (cacheDirectory.canWrite()){
                    File dir = new File (cacheDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/IMGDir");
                    dir.mkdirs();
                    // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
                    File tmpFile = new File(dir,  "/myimg_"+position+".png");
                    Log.i("Temp:", cacheDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
                    // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                    FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                    // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

                    // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);

                    // Flush the FileOutputStream
                    fOutStream.flush();

                    //Close the FileOutputStream
                    fOutStream.close();

                    // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
                    HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                    // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                    hmBitmap.put("img",tmpFile.getPath());

                    // Storing the position of the image in the listview
                    hmBitmap.put("position",position);

                    Log.i("HMB:", hmBitmap.toString());
                    // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
                    return hmBitmap;
                }

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
            if(result != null) {
                // Getting the path to the downloaded image
                String path = (String) result.get("img");

                // Getting the position of the downloaded image
                int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

                // Get listview
                //lv = getListView();

                // Getting adapter of the listview
                SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) lv.getAdapter();

                // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the listview
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);
                Log.i("POS:", adapter.getItem(position).toString());
                // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter
                hm.put("image",path);

                Log.i("POS 2:", adapter.getItem(position).toString());
                // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
                //setListAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help in finding the connection

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your approach seems a little unconventional... Can you post your adapter code?  In the meantime, take a look at this and see if anything in here helps you: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html It may be that your `ImageView` needs to know which task has targeted it, so that when it's recycled, you don't have competing tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment... There is no adapter code in this case since i'm already extending ListActivity... also i did not want to deviate from this train of thought. The challenge to solve using this particular approach drives me :)

Comment: in your from/to maps for your adapter, I don't see any references to the image/ImageView, so now I'm really confused, I don't see how the adapter binds the image to the ImageView

Comment: My approach is based on this tut http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-lazy-loading-images-and-text-in-listview-from-http-json-data/, while he fetches json array data i'm using json object but essentially the adapter changes putting the new image url and location just fine. The tut does not show the references to ImageView either but works. I'm wondering where I'm going wrong. If I fail to accomplish this then i'd have to follow the more conventional custom Adapter approach... but i just had to try :)

Answer (score 0):

- `SimpleAdapter` does not have the capability for the "scroll for more" dynamic updating you are trying to do. From the docs:

  > An easy adapter to map static data to views defined in an XML file.

  Once you pass in the list of maps for the data, there's no way for `SimpleAdapter` to notice that you've updated that list.
- Also, to effectively display images even with static data, you need use a subclass with `setViewImage` overridden or define a `ViewBinder` that can map images and call `adapter.setViewBinder` so that the adapter knows how to bind an image to your data.

To achieve what you are trying to do, you will need to create a subclass of `BaseAdapter` so that you can dynamically add data and correctly bind images to the `ImageView`.